# Do I need to prune my leaning Meyer

Tags: pruning, citrus

My Meyer lemon previously had a problem with some spotty yellowing of its leaves shortly after purchase as per this [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/30327/why-do-the-leaves-on-my-meyer-lemon-have-blotchy-yellow-areas) but seems to have largely recovered. However, the stem is on a serious lean on account of the heavy fruit on its branches.

[image: leaning Meyer]

And the main stem has a split in it as well which can't be helping

[image: split in the stem]

And there appears to be some mild early magnesium deficiency with tip chlorosis

[image: tip chlorosis]

So, should I just cut the stem below the split to alleviate both problems and let it bush out below the prune?  Or just remove the fruit?